# How can I keep XML data together after an XSLT? (In MS-Access)

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to parse XML data that comes to me as attribute-centric, into an element-centric style using an XSL Transformation. My goal is to be able to import it into an access database. I've succeeded in parsing it into elements, but my issue now resides in the data being split into multiple tables. I've got multiple categories of element tags, but after the parse when the xsl creates 'blank' header tags for sections, access splits into a new table when it hits the blank tag. The structure is (simply)

MeterReadings(with small description attributes)

MetersRead(with small description attributes)

Meter(with the majority of description attributes I need)

Status(with small description attributes)

What happens is the XSL creates all of the attributes into elements but then leaves the headers (MeterReadings,MetersRead,Meter,Status) as blank elements. This causes access to separate these 4 into separate tables, which ends up almost creating useless data as the majority of data in 'Meter' requires the identifiers from the 'MeterReadings' and so on.

I'm a student programmer on placement and brand new to XML/XSLT. Currently my XSL looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is how my XML looks after transformation, I have around 150k lines of data before the transformation so you can't see MeterReadings in this snip, because it would have to encompass around 1700 lines to see it encapsulated.

```
<MetersRead>
<Meter>
<MeterIrn>(Dummy Data)</MeterIrn>
<MeterName>(Dummy Data)</MeterName>
<IsActive>(Dummy Data)</IsActive>
<SerialNumber>(Dummy Data)</SerialNumber>
<MeterType>(Dummy Data)</MeterType>
<Description></Description>
<InstallDate>(Dummy Data)</InstallDate>
<RemovalDate></RemovalDate>
<AccountIdent></AccountIdent>
<AccountName></AccountName>
<SdpIdent>(Dummy Data)</SdpIdent>
<Location>(Dummy Data)</Location>
<TimeZoneIndex>(Dummy Data)</TimeZoneIndex>
<Timezone>(Dummy Data)</Timezone>
<TimeZoneOffset>(Dummy Data)</TimeZoneOffset>
<ObservesDaylightSavings>(Dummy Data)</ObservesDaylightSavings>
<MediaType>(Dummy Data)</MediaType>
<Status>
<Code>(Dummy Data)</Code>
<Text>(Dummy Data)</Text>
</Status>
</Meter>
```

So hopefully you can see what I mean here, where MetersRead / Meter / Status are open blank tags, this is where MS-Access will split a new table, and anything up until the next blank open tag will go into its own table. Any tips are extremely appreciated, I've spent the last few days delving through questions on here, MSDN help, and other resources. I've learned a lot from @Lingamurthy CS on here.

Also this is what my XML looks like BEFORE transformation if that helps explain my case

```
<MetersRead >

    <Meter MeterIrn="(Dummy Data)" MeterName="(Dummy Data)" IsActive="(Dummy Data)" SerialNumber="(Dummy Data)" MeterType="(Dummy Data)" Description="" InstallDate="(Dummy Data)" RemovalDate="" AccountIdent="" AccountName="" SdpIdent="(Dummy Data)" Location="(Dummy Data)" TimeZoneIndex="(Dummy Data)" Timezone="(Dummy Data)" TimeZoneOffset="(Dummy Data)" ObservesDaylightSavings="(Dummy Data)" MediaType="(Dummy Data)" >

        <Status Code="(Dummy Data)" Text="(Dummy Data)" />

    </Meter>
```

[Access Table Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DavFT.png)
The image shows how Access import formats my tables, and you can see that it is splitting the 4 highlighted tables whereas the data is only useful if it stays together in say 1 generic "Meter" table. I tried moving fields over to one table such that when the import happens and I only append data to existing fields it would populate it how I needed, but it only fills the tables it can fully identify as the same structure from the XML.

Comment: I see your transform, and the data, and the actual result.  What I *don't* see and am uncertain about is what form you want the output to take instead.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look John. What I'm trying to achieve is keeping the data in relevant blocks so that all the meter data stays together and is still useful. I'm trying to figure out (or wrap my head around) either how to omit blank tags such that the Access import only creates a few or one big table with all of the relevant data together. I'll edit my post with some snips from my Access so you can see how it gets imported and why it's an issue.

Comment: The information about what Access does with the output of the transform isn't particularly helpful.  I need to know how you want the output of the XSL transform to differ from what it is now.  Do you just want omit the elements that arise other than from transforming attributes?  That seems strange to me, because those elements are necessary to preserve the structure of the data (in the XML sense), but if it's what you want then it is easy enough to accomplish.

Comment: I believe that's what I need to achieve, yes. Apologies for the indirect approach to my question, I'm having a hard time trying to articulate it myself. What I would like to do (basically) is be able to pinpoint tags to keep together. So say in my XSL, I'm trying to figure out how I can create an element block for all of the data in Meter or Meter Readings, and just post it all to one table. I'm thinking I need some form of code to set a template for say MeterReadings that encapsulates all of its attributes + the data within Meter + the data within Status. Or along that train of thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem not to be certain exactly what you want.  As best I can interpret your data and request, I think you want each `<Meter>` element to correspond to one row in one flat table.  `<MetersRead>` is just a collection of the `<Meter>` elements, so it corresponds to that same table, not a separate one of its own, and `<Status>` elements are to be flattened into the data for their containing `<Meter>`.  How any of that relates to a `MeterReadings` element is unclear and cannot be addressed based on the information provided.

The main thing to understand about the "blank" open tags -- i.e. the ones that correspond to elements, rather than attributes, of the input document -- is that they arise from the `<xsl:copy>` in your stylesheet's identity transform.  The key to omitting them is to apply a different transform to elements that should not have corresponding elements in the output tree.  You can easily transform an element without copying the element itself.

Something along these lines is probably closer to what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- BY DEFAULT, elements and text nodes are copied,
       and elements' attributes and contents are transformed as child nodes
       of the output element -->
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- By default, attributes are transformed to elements -->
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Certain elements have only their contents transformed -->
  <xsl:template match="MetersRead | Status">
    <!-- no xsl:copy, and attribute children, if any, are ignored -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I had to patch up your example input by closing the `<MetersRead>` element; the result of applying the above transformation to the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Meter>
  <MeterIrn>(Dummy Data)</MeterIrn>
  <MeterName>(Dummy Data)</MeterName>
  <IsActive>(Dummy Data)</IsActive>
  <SerialNumber>(Dummy Data)</SerialNumber>
  <MeterType>(Dummy Data)</MeterType>
  <Description/>
  <InstallDate>(Dummy Data)</InstallDate>
  <RemovalDate/>
  <AccountIdent/>
  <AccountName/>
  <SdpIdent>(Dummy Data)</SdpIdent>
  <Location>(Dummy Data)</Location>
  <TimeZoneIndex>(Dummy Data)</TimeZoneIndex>
  <Timezone>(Dummy Data)</Timezone>
  <TimeZoneOffset>(Dummy Data)</TimeZoneOffset>
  <ObservesDaylightSavings>(Dummy Data)</ObservesDaylightSavings>
  <MediaType>(Dummy Data)</MediaType>
  <Code>(Dummy Data)</Code>
  <Text>(Dummy Data)</Text>
</Meter>
```

Note the absence of any `<MetersRead>` element and the flattening of the erstwhile `<Status>` into the host `<Meter>`.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head with this response, and regardless thank you for your efforts, they're helping me understand this more and more. The comments you put into the XSL have helped me understand what's happening and where, and it's helping me realize what I need to change to pull in the data I need. I think I'm a few steps away from where I need to be, but this has narrowed down my target area tenfold. Apologies I can't up vote your answer John, thank you again.

Comment: Nice to see a C-programmer answer an XSLT question! By the way, it sounds like *Meter* elements repeat, so might want to keep its parent, *MetersRead*. MS Access should then read in one table.

Comment: I'm a man of many talents, @Parfait.  Anyway, although it's unclear what exactly the OP wants, getting rid of the `<MetersRead>` element is one of the things he seemed more confident about.  If he changes his mind, though, then I think it is clear enough how he could get them back.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant info, but what I'm trying to achieve is creating a table of data in access such that someone with 0 programming experience can look into the database and view the information they need out of the XML all in one table. I'm very inexperienced in XML/XSLT so my way of figuring out what I needed to do was to remove tags where I could, such that when the transform happens, the relevant data was all encapsulated into similar blocks (ie. Meter and all of its data) so that access would accept it all into one table. I realize my method is probably flawed, 3rd day with XSLT!